# Testing our CMake Modules

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cmake, cmake-modules

We created multiple additional functions for CMake. They became quite a lot, and we need to (unit) test them.

There are simple ones, that are only variable bases like:

```
function(join_list LIST GLUE)
```

These can be tested with a custom CMake Script, that checks the results.
For this we also wrote a set of assert-macros.

This becomes way harder when the functions are target based:

```
function(target_my_custom_property_set TARGET VALUE)
```

We need a multiple CMakeLists.txt Files that need to be configured. Configuration must succeed or fail with specified messages. Also the result files must be checked.

I wonder, is there an easier way? Is there a existing framework? How does Kitware test the shipped modules?

Answer (score 2):

`ctest` is the framework for running all sorts of tests.  There are *many* tests for `cmake` that get run as part of the [CMake Testing Process](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Help/dev/testing.rst).  These tests are part of the source code in the [Tests](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/master/Tests) folder and are part of `CMakeLists.txt`.

The specific tests you want to look at are located in the `RunCMake` folder.  These tests utilize `RunCMake.cmake`.  A good example is the tests in `message`.  What these tests do is utilize `execute_process` to capture the output from `cmake` and compare the output from the `cmake` configure step to the contents for a file with the expected output.  The return value from `cmake` is also returned and can be tested.

You don't specify what "results files" are. There are examples that are more complicated that the perform a configuration and build and scan some files to verify there contents.

It may be easier if you separate out checking messages in a failed configure vs a failed build vs a passing configure and build and a specific output message.

Answer (score 0):

More then 4 years passed and I still struggle with this. However, one solution we use is to mock the target based functions:

```
function(set_target_properties)
   assert(${CMAKE_ARGC} == 8)
   # more asserts....
endfunction()

target_my_custom_property_set(tar val)
```

This often is enough to test those functions.